# How does tf.nn.conv2d calculate its values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've looked at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn/convolution) for `tf.nn.conv2d` but it didn't really help much. So I tried to multiply the first 4 values of my input array that form a square `(0, 1, 2, 2.5)` with the first column of the `filter_weights` array `(0.19041163, -0.36705261, 0.69018674, 1.7655524)`. But regardless of how I multiply these values I'm not getting `1.13938534`, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below I have the code that I used.

Given an array:

```
x = np.array([
[0, 1, 0.5, 10],
[2, 2.5, 1, -8],
[4, 0, 5, 6],
[15, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=np.float32).reshape((1, 4, 4, 1))

X = tf.constant(x)
```

And weights:

```
filter_weights = tf.truncated_normal([2,2,1,3])
```

Which prints:

```
[[[[ 0.19041163  0.59322315  0.27544078]]

  [[-0.36705261 -1.18738699  1.45393717]]]


 [[[ 0.69018674  1.08702338 -1.15911126]]

  [[ 1.76255524 -1.42660797 -0.18624328]]]]
```

How does:

```
strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]
padding = "SAME"
tf.nn.conv2d(input, F_W, strides, padding)
```

Give:

```
 [[[[  1.13938534  -5.06340981  -4.23629761]
   [-18.01530266  -4.67841816  16.20156288]]

  [[ -9.49576092  -4.87288237   6.77371216]
   [ -0.57718992 -12.70932484   0.89242649]]]]
```

Comment: What are you using for strides?

Comment: Wow didn't even occur to me that I didn't add the strides! I've updated the question!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I am guessing the error you are making is that you are printing the weight matrix and convolution outputs in separate sess.run calls? Remember the weight matrix is randomly generated on each graph execution since you are using [truncated_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors#truncated_normal).